# Retrieve value from mongoose object after query

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, backend

I have a query as follows :

```
await Categories.findOne({slug : _gender} , { _id : 0 , categories :{$elemMatch :  {slug : _mainCategory}}})
```

and the model is this :

```
const categoriesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  title: { type: String },
  slug: { type: String }, ==> match first param with this
  categories: [
    {
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      title: { type: String },
      slug: { type: String }, ==> match the second param with this
      categories: [ ==> retrieve this field
        {
          _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          title: { type: String },
          slug: { type: String },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```

`_gender` and `_mainCategory` are params.

The output it gives is as follows:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": "12",
            "title": "Ayakkabı",
            "slug": "kadin-ayakkabi", // ==> this is the  { _id : 0 , categories :{$elemMatch :  {slug : _mainCategory}} part, one level above this is the part which matches the {slug : _gender}
            "image": "https://webizade.com/bm/img/",
            "categories": [ // ===> this is the value I want to retrieve after the query
                {
                    "id": "100",
                    "title": "Topuklu Ayakkabı",
                    "filter_title": "ayakkabi",
                    "slug": "kadin-topuklu-ayakkabi-x-g1-c107",
                    "image": "https://webizade.com/bm/img/"
                },
                {
                    "id": "101",
                    "title": "Spor Ayakkabı",
                    "filter_title": "ayakkabi",
                    "slug": "spor-ayakkabi",
                    "image": "https://webizade.com/bm/img/"
                },
                {
                    "id": "102",
                    "title": "Günlük Ayakkabı",
                    "filter_title": "ayakkabi",
                    "slug": "kadin-gunluk-ayakkabi-x-g1-c1352",
                    "image": "https://webizade.com/bm/img/"
                },
                {
                    "id": "103",
                    "title": "Babet",
                    "filter_title": "ayakkabi",
                    "slug": "kadin-babet-x-g1-c113",
                    "image": "https://webizade.com/bm/img/"
                },
                {
                    "id": "104",
                    "title": "Sandalet",
                    "filter_title": "ayakkabi",
                    "slug": "kadin-sandalet-x-g1-c111",
                    "image": "https://webizade.com/bm/img/"
                },
                {
                    "id": "105",
                    "title": "Terlik",
                    "filter_title": "ayakkabi",
                    "slug": "kadin-terlik-x-g1-c110",
                    "image": "https://webizade.com/bm/img/"
                },
                {
                    "id": "144",
                    "title": "Kar Botu",
                    "filter_title": "ayakkabi",
                    "slug": "kar-botu",
                    "image": "https://webizade.com/bm/img/"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As far as matching the correct object goes, this is correct. However, I want to retrieve the "categories" array inside the outer categories array after finding the correct object. But I don't know the correct syntax for doing that.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add your desired output to better understand the question

Comment: I want the array "categories" : [{"id" : 100 , ""title" : "Topuklu Ayakkabi"} ....]

Comment: Did you try `.findOne(.....).select('categories.categories')`?

Comment: Yes, it gives a  MongoError: Path collision at categories.categories remaining portion categories error

Comment: please add the schema of the category collection to help you better.

Comment: added the model, and marked the fields to match and the desired out put field